# How did やわらかい gain its い?

Tags: etymology, adjectives

As we know, there is a class of adjectives that end in `〜らか`:  `滑【なめ】らか`, `明【あき】らか`, `清【きよ】らか`, `安【やす】らか`, etc.

`やわらか` (`柔らか` or `軟らか`) is also in this class of adjectives.  However, it can also be written as the イ-adjective `やわらかい`.  So when and how did this adjective pick up an い to become a separate イ-adjective?

Can this be done arbitrarily with any of the `〜らか` class adjectives?  Like `滑【なめ】らかい`, `明【あき】らかい`, `清【きよ】らかい`, `安【やす】らかい`.  My gut feeling is that it cannot, but only because those forms sound strange to me.  If it cannot arbitrarily be done, are there any other `〜らか` class adjectives that **can** take on the extra い?

Comment: やわらか does not work as a na-adjective. It is only i-adjective.

Comment: Related: [Unifying concept for noun-adjectives of the pattern Xかな](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/5717/542)

Comment: We can say やわらかな. http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/223492/m0u/%E6%9F%94%E3%82%89%E3%81%8B/

Comment: Wow I haven't noticed, how interesting... goo辞書 says やわらかな is 「[形動]」, and it says やわらかい is「[形]」,「形容動詞「やわらか」の形容詞化」. I can't think of any other ~~らか words that can be i-adjectives... Maybe やわらか(い) is a very unique word...?

Comment: Interesting.  やわらかい is the only adjective ending with らかい listed in either Daijirin or Daijisen.

Comment: I wish to remember reading somewhere that Japanese tend to prefer い-adjectives, which is reflected by the fact that there are a lot more of them. Perhaps some of the above natives can confirm this. Then it's quite possible that it simply "turned into" an い-adjective, much like 新しい originated from 新たな.

Answer (score 6):

Firstly, as was noted in the comments (by Tsuyoshi Ito), that the same thing cannot be done with other adjectives ending in `～らか`.

On the other hand, there exists a number of adjectives, which can function both as イ-adjective and as ナ-adjective, e.g.

```
大きい   大きな
小さい   小さな
真っ白い 真っ白な (etc.)
細かい   細かな
暖かい   暖かな
四角い   四角な (etc.)
柔らかい 柔らかな
```

(but, of course, やわらかい is the only one ending in `～らかい`). An investigation of the differences here might deserve a separate question.

As for the difference in usage, I have talked to quite a few native speakers, who maintain that there is no substantial difference in meaning between `やわらかい` and `やわらかな`, which is only a handful of anecdotal evidence. On the other hand, [here](http://www.yano.bc.ca/vansin/vansinpo095.htm) is an article (blog post?) about the difference between `やわらかいお餅` and `やわらかなお餅`, where the author says something along the lines, that a `やわらかなお餅` has a more gentle feel to it (he says `「やわらかな」のほうが落ち着く感じがする`). Which, too, is at best anecdotal evidence.

One can only guess that maybe he means that `やわらかい` is a more objective statement about the physical properties of the `お餅` (softness), whereas `やわらかな` suggests a subjective experience of softness, or rather gentleness.

But even if this is the case, not every Japanese person seems to perceive these subtleties in the same way...

P.S. I noticed that I haven't answered your question, regarding the history of the difference. I will delete my answer, if it isn't contributing anything to the problem of answering your question.